# Increase the size of bootcamp of Windows 7 on virtual machine

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, disk-space

Someone just helped me install `VMWare Fusion` and `Windows 7` as virtual machine.

And I realize that the disk `BOOTCAMP (C:)` for `Windows 7` is just 39.90 Go, which will be too small... The `disk Z` is the shared folder with Mac OS.

Is there any way to increse the size of the disk `BOOTCAMP (C:)` for `Windows 7`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the application [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to do this. It's not an extremely simple process, since, "The problem is that if you resize your boot/system partition, you will be completely unable to boot without repairing windows," according to this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/) from How-To Geek. However, that same guide will guide you through the entire process of doing so.

Mac Rumors has a list of [several alternate methods](http://guides.macrumors.com/Extend/Resize_Boot_Camp_Partition) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: OK, that means it has been fixed when we installed this Windows 7 as virtual machine? But I really don't remember when we parameterd it while installing

Comment: Sorry, I must clarify one thing: though it is called `BOOTCAMP (C:)`, the Windows 7 is definitely as a virtual machine under VMWare, I don't have dual boot systems.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using VMWare to virtualize the bootcamp partition. So you never actually ran the bootcamp setup?

Comment: I don't have dual systems, I always need to run Mac OS, then virtual machine, then choose Windows 7 as virtual machine...

Comment: Not having dual-boot is unlikely, since the partition is called BOOTCAMP, which means at *some* stage, the Bootcamp setup was run.

Comment: While it does seem likely that you indeed have setup dual boot using Bootcamp at some point, you can confirm by restarting your machine and keeping the `Option` key pressed as it boots up. This will show you the list of volumes you can boot from. If you have dual boot, you'd see an option to boot from Windows here.